# TypeError: tours.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each time I try to map it, it gives me this error. Here's the code below:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Tours from './Tours';



function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
                    tourInfo();
               }, []);

  const tourInfo = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/films`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setTours(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    catch (error) {
                    setLoading(false);
                    console.log(error);
                  }

  };


  if (loading) {
    `<Loading />`
  }
  return (
    `<div className="App">`
      {tours.map(tour => (
                `<Tours />`
              ))}
    `</div>`
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, the problem is that OP is setting the data to the response of the fetch call, which returns an object with an array called `results`. They should be setting the `tours` variable to `data.results`, not the big `data` object itself. This is React with `useState`, so async things work fine

Comment: "async things work fine" -- except when they don't, like if you `useState(null)` -- but I get your meaning, @Samathingamajig.

Answer (score 4):

`data` is an object and has no map function. the movies is accessed by `results` from the data value:

```
  const response = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/films`);
  const data = await response.json();
  setTours(data.results);
  setLoading(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check what's returned by that url!
I've checked it out. it returns an object not an array.
That's why you get this error.

You should set result value to the tours state, like this:

```
setTours('results' in data ? data.results:[]);
```